# AWS Lambda & Node | Error: Runtime exited without providing a reason Runtime.ExitError

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I had get this error on AWS Lambda, while updating runtime from node14 to node18.

```
Error: Runtime exited without providing a reason Runtime.ExitError
Phase: invoke Status: error Error Type: Runtime.ExitError
```

Initially it was difficult to figure out the actual root cause because error was enough to understand some people who are new in this.

Some troubleshoot aws provided in this [link](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-runtime-error)

In my case, i was using aws-sdk which is on javascript v2, that was the reason the lambda is breaking for node18.

fix - use aws-sdk v3 with node18 and error get resolved. migration to v3 [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/migrating.html) If you have fix the issue with some other way, please do add in answer.

I'm sharing my experience here because during my debugging process, I struggled to find relevant resources to address this issue.